# What is the pythonic way of building full urls for links?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a way to build urls in python3 without having to do string concatenation. I get that I can

```
import requests
url_endpoint = 'https://www.duckduckgo.com'
mydict = {'q': 'whee! Stanford!!!', 'something': 'else'}
resp = requests.get(url_endpoint, params=mydict)
print(resp.url) # THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I WANT
```

or

```
from requests import Request, Session
s = Session()
req = Request('GET',  url, params={'q': 'blah'})
print(req.url)
# I didn't get this to work, but from the docs 
#   it should build the url without making the call
```

or

```
url = baseurl + "?" + urllib.urlencode(params)
```

I like that the request library intelligently decides to drop `?` if it isn't needed, but that code actually makes a full GET request so instead of just building a full text url (which I plan to dump to an html tag). I am using django, but I didn't see anything to help with that in the core library.

Comment: Maybe if you build a [`requests.Request`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Request) or `requests.PreparedRequest` (which won't send it), you can get the URL out of that object.

Comment: Are you aware of [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse)?

Comment: ``req.url`` will contain the url after redirections, so it needs a request to be populated.

Comment: If to be done offline, there's of course [`urlunparse()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunparse).

Comment: urlunparse has an unwieldy method signature, requiring 6 paramaters as a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django comes with [`QueryDict`s](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) which basically do everything you want.

```
def make_url(url, args=None):
    query = QueryDict(mutable=True)
    query.update(args or {})
    return '{}{}{}'.format(url, '?' if query else '', query.urlencode())
```

It supports multiple values per argument just like you can encounter in a url: `example.com/foo?a=1&a=2&a=3`.

Comment: Why use QueryDict over:
`url = '{}{}{}'.format(baseurl, '?' if query else '', urllib.parse.urlencode(params)`?